# Scrolling issues on Mobile

Tags: html, css

I need help with my contact form, the screen isn't in fixed position and some element is making the page being able to scroll on mobile when its not supposed to since everything is aligned in the center. I tried removing padding in container in the Mobile query but that did not work and I can't seem to find out why its scrolling, I changed the viewport to 100% width and that fixed the issue but that will not work in the long run since my website is supposed to be responsive and I changed the viewport back to initial scale and everything as seen in the HTML code but the scrolling issue comes back.

**CSS** and **HTML**

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) /* Mobile */ {






  * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#navigation {
display: none;


}



input[type=text3], select, textarea {
    width: 55%; /* Full width */
    padding: 30px; /* Some padding */ 
    margin-top: 0px;
    outline: none;
    color: #ff0055;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #f3f3f3; /* Gray border */
    border-radius: 100px; /* Rounded borders */
    
    }
 
 
 
 
 input[type=text2], select, textarea {
    width: 55%; /* Full width */
    padding: 20px; /* Some padding */ 
    color: #ff0055;
    outline: none;
    text-align: center; 
    border: 1px solid #f3f3f3; /* Gray border */
    border-radius: 100px; /* Rounded borders */
    
    }

    input[type=text2]:hover, select, textarea {
    width: 55%; /* Full width */
    padding: 20px; /* Some padding */ 
    color: #ff0055;
    text-align: center; 
    border: 2px solid #ff0055; /* Gray border */
    border-radius: 100px; /* Rounded borders */
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    }

    input[type=text3]:hover, select, textarea {
    width: 55%; /* Full width */
    padding: 30px; /* Some padding */ 
    margin-top: 0px;
    color: #ff0055;
    text-align: center; 
    border: 2px solid #ff0055; /* Gray border */
    border-radius: 100px; /* Rounded borders */
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    }


 input[type=text], select, textarea {
    width: 55%; /* Full width */
    padding: 20px; /* Some padding */ 
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
    color: #FF0055;
    border: 1px solid #f3f3f3; /* Gray border */
    border-radius: 100px; /* Rounded borders */
    
    }

    input[type=text]:hover, select, textarea {
    width: 55%;
    padding: 20px; /* Some padding */ 
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #ff0055; /* Gray border */
    border-radius: 50px; /* Rounded borders */
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    }



input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #001FFF;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: none; 
    margin: 50px 175px;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 100px;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}


input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #0019CF;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 20px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 20px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0px 20px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

 
.container {
    border-radius: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
  }




.nav2 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.nav2 > .nav-header {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.nav2 > .nav-header > .nav-title {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  padding: 5px 10px 10px 15px;
}
#header {
display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 10000;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  padding: 5px 10px 10px 15px;
}

.nav2 > .nav-btn {
  display: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav2 > .nav-links {
  display: inline;
  z-index: 9999;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: right;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.nav2 > .nav-links > a {
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 9999;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 13px 10px 13px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.nav2 > .nav-links > a:hover {
  background-color: #005DFF;
  color: white;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.nav2 > #nav-check {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
  .nav2 > .nav-btn {
    z-index: 9999;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  .nav2 > .nav-btn > label {
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 9999;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 13px;
  }
  .nav2 > .nav-btn > label:hover {
    background-color: blue);
    z-index: 9999;
  }
  .nav2 > .nav-btn > label > span {
    display: block;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 25px;
    height: 10px;
    border-top: 3px solid black;
  }
  .nav2 > .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 0px;
    z-index: 9999;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
  }
  .nav2 > .nav-links > a {
    display: block;
    z-index: 9999;
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav2> #nav-check:not(:checked) + .nav-links {
    height: 0px;
    z-index: 9999;
  }
  .nav2 > #nav-check:checked + .nav-links {
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    z-index: 9999;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}

}
.button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 130%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 32px 24px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border-color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: none;
   align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #FF0055;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}



@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
    background: #ffffff;
   
}

p {
text-align: center;

}

h1 {
text-align: center;
padding: 100px;
font-weight: bolder;
}

h2 {
padding: 10px 10px;
font-weight: bolder;
}

h3 {
font-weight: bolder;
top: 50%;
    left: -10%;
    transform: translate(0%, -100%);
}



#header.active {
     box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
     -webkit-animation: fadein 1s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 1s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 1s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 1s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 1s;
}   

a:link {
  position: relative;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
color: #000000;  
}

a:link:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.nav:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.active:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

a:link {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:link:hover {
   padding: 13px;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: height 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: height 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: height 0.5s ease;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
            
}

a:link:active {
   padding: 13px;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: height 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: height 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: height 0.5s ease;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
            
}

a:visited {
color: #000000;
}



#header.scroll {
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.5;
}



.main {
border-radius: 100px;
padding: 13px;
border: none!important;
text-decoration: none!important

}

.main:hover {
background-color: #00439F;
color: white;
border: none;
padding: 13px;
text-decoration: none!important;
box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: fixed;
    margin: -13px -90px;
    border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-animation:bounce 1s infinite;
}

</style>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/michalsnik/aos/2.1.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>adamferreira - Contact</title>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/michalsnik/aos/2.1.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">adamferreira</div>
<div id="navigation"
<ul>
    <a class="main" href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
    <a class="nav" href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="nav" href="contact.php">Contact</a>
    <a class="nav" href="featured.html">Featured</a>
    <a class="nav" href="story-highlights.html">Story Highlights</a>
</ul>

    
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="nav2">
    <div class="nav-header">
      <div class="nav-title"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-btn">
      <label for="nav-check">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-check">
    <div class="nav-links">
      <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
      <a href="featured.html">Featured</a>
      <a href="story-highlights.html">Story Highlights</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</head>
<body>
<div class="headerBackground"></div>

<div class="container" data-aos="ease-in-out-back" data-aos="zoom out">
<h1>Contact</h1>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..." style="font-size: 15px;">
    <input type="text2" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..." style="font-size: 15px;">
    <input type="text3" name="comment" placeholder="Type your comment..." style="font-size: 15px;">
    
    <input type="submit" class="btn" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The div with `id="navigation"` missing closing brackets and also there are 2 closing divs after `</ul>` which has not starting tag.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that didn't seem to work ethier :(

Comment: The final height of #container is larger than screen height. Why it should stop scrolling?

Comment: where do you see that? Lol but i mean on mobile its supposed to be zoomed out by default and if you zoom out manually everything is more tiny than usual.

Answer (score 1):

Your `submit` button is absolutely massive due to the `margin: 50px 175px;`. Just the margins take up `350px`. Factor in the actual width of the button (50px) and you have `400px` right there.

If you set a viewport tag (`width=device-width`), you're looking at 375px (or so) for an iPhone 6/7/8. So, excluding any other margin/padding to the body, you're already overflowing.

[image]
[image]

### Edit:

Rather than use a defined value to center/offset the button, you could change `display` from `inline-block` to `block`. Then `margin: 50px 175px` to `margin: 50px auto`; which will center. `flexbox` would also help, but requires a bit more changes to the container/children.

Here's the rendered HTML/CSS after adjusting `submit` to `display: block; margin: 50px auto` (no more horizontal scroll!):
[image]

```css
 @media screen and (max-width: 500px) 
/* Mobile */
 {
 * {
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 #navigation {
     display: none;
}
 input[type=text3], select, textarea {
     width: 55%;
    /* Full width */
     padding: 30px;
    /* Some padding */
     margin-top: 0px;
     outline: none;
     color: #ff0055;
     text-align: center;
     border: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
    /* Gray border */
     border-radius: 100px;
    /* Rounded borders */
}
 input[type=text2], select, textarea {
     width: 55%;
    /* Full width */
     padding: 20px;
    /* Some padding */
     color: #ff0055;
     outline: none;
     text-align: center;
     border: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
    /* Gray border */
     border-radius: 100px;
    /* Rounded borders */
}
 input[type=text2]:hover, select, textarea {
     width: 55%;
    /* Full width */
     padding: 20px;
    /* Some padding */
     color: #ff0055;
     text-align: center;
     border: 2px solid #ff0055;
    /* Gray border */
     border-radius: 100px;
    /* Rounded borders */
     transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
 input[type=text3]:hover, select, textarea {
     width: 55%;
    /* Full width */
     padding: 30px;
    /* Some padding */
     margin-top: 0px;
     color: #ff0055;
     text-align: center;
     border: 2px solid #ff0055;
    /* Gray border */
     border-radius: 100px;
    /* Rounded borders */
     transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
 input[type=text], select, textarea {
     width: 55%;
    /* Full width */
     padding: 20px;
    /* Some padding */
     text-align: center;
     outline: none;
     color: #FF0055;
     border: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
    /* Gray border */
     border-radius: 100px;
    /* Rounded borders */
}
 input[type=text]:hover, select, textarea {
     width: 55%;
     padding: 20px;
    /* Some padding */
     text-align: center;
     border: 2px solid #ff0055;
    /* Gray border */
     border-radius: 50px;
    /* Rounded borders */
     transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
 input[type=submit] {
     background-color: #001FFF;
     color: white;
     font-size: 16px;
     font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
     border: none;
     cursor: pointer;
     border-color: #000000;
     text-align: center;
     display: block;
     text-decoration: none;
     text-shadow: none;
     margin: 50px auto;
     padding: 10px 50px;
     border: none;
     border-radius: 100px;
     outline: none;
     cursor: pointer;
}
 input[type=submit]:hover {
     background-color: #0019CF;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
     outline: none;
     -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 20px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0px 20px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
     box-shadow: 0px 20px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
 .container {
     border-radius: 100%;
     font-size: 20px;
     text-align: center;
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
     display: inline-block;
}
 .nav2 {
     height: 50px;
     width: 100%;
     margin: 0 auto;
     background-color: white;
     position: fixed;
     z-index: 9999;
}
 .nav2 > .nav-header {
     display: inline;
     margin: 0 auto;
     z-index: 9999;
}
 .nav2 > .nav-header > .nav-title {
     display: inline-block;
     font-size: 20px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     color: #fff;
     font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
     padding: 5px 10px 10px 15px;
}
 #header {
     display: inline-block;
     font-size: 20px;
     position: fixed;
     margin: 0 auto;
     color: #000;
     z-index: 10000;
     font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
     padding: 5px 10px 10px 15px;
}
 .nav2 > .nav-btn {
     display: none;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
 .nav2 > .nav-links {
     display: inline;
     z-index: 9999;
     margin: 0 auto;
     float: right;
     font-size: 15px;
}
 .nav2 > .nav-links > a {
     display: inline-block;
     z-index: 9999;
     margin: 0 auto;
     text-align: center;
     background-color: white;
     padding: 13px 10px 13px 10px;
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #000;
}
 .nav2 > .nav-links > a:hover {
     background-color: #005DFF;
     color: white;
     z-index: 9999;
}
 .nav2 > #nav-check {
     display: none;
}
 @media (max-width:600px) {
     .nav2 > .nav-btn {
         z-index: 9999;
         display: inline-block;
         position: absolute;
         right: 0px;
         top: 0px;
    }
     .nav2 > .nav-btn > label {
         display: inline-block;
         z-index: 9999;
         background-color: white;
         color: black;
         width: 50px;
         height: 50px;
         padding: 13px;
    }
     .nav2 > .nav-btn > label:hover {
         background-color: blue);
         z-index: 9999;
    }
     .nav2 > .nav-btn > label > span {
         display: block;
         z-index: 9999;
         width: 25px;
         height: 10px;
         border-top: 3px solid black;
    }
     .nav2 > .nav-links {
         position: absolute;
         display: block;
         width: 100%;
         background-color: #fff;
         height: 0px;
         z-index: 9999;
         transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
         overflow-y: hidden;
         top: 50px;
         left: 0px;
    }
     .nav2 > .nav-links > a {
         display: block;
         z-index: 9999;
         color: black;
         width: 100%;
    }
     .nav2> #nav-check:not(:checked) + .nav-links {
         height: 0px;
         z-index: 9999;
    }
     .nav2 > #nav-check:checked + .nav-links {
         height: calc(100vh - 50px);
         z-index: 9999;
         overflow-y: auto;
    }
}
}
 .button {
 position: absolute;
 top: 130%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 color: black;
 font-size: 16px;
 padding: 32px 24px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 border: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 100px;
 border-color: #000000;
 text-align: center;
 display: flex;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: none;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}
 .button:hover {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 color: #FF0055;
 text-shadow: none;
 text-decoration: none;
}
 @keyframes fadein {
 from {
     opacity: 0;
}
 to {
     opacity: 1;
}
}
/* Firefox < 16 */
 @-moz-keyframes fadein {
 from {
     opacity: 0;
}
 to {
     opacity: 1;
}
}
/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
 @-webkit-keyframes fadein {
 from {
     opacity: 0;
}
 to {
     opacity: 1;
}
}
/* Internet Explorer */
 @-ms-keyframes fadein {
 from {
     opacity: 0;
}
 to {
     opacity: 1;
}
}
/* Opera < 12.1 */
 @-o-keyframes fadein {
 from {
     opacity: 0;
}
 to {
     opacity: 1;
}
}
 body, html {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
 background: #ffffff;
}
 p {
 text-align: center;
}
 h1 {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 100px;
 font-weight: bolder;
}
 h2 {
 padding: 10px 10px;
 font-weight: bolder;
}
 h3 {
 font-weight: bolder;
 top: 50%;
 left: -10%;
 transform: translate(0%, -100%);
}
 #header.active {
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 -webkit-animation: fadein 1s;
/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
 -moz-animation: fadein 1s;
/* Firefox < 16 */
 -ms-animation: fadein 1s;
/* Internet Explorer */
 -o-animation: fadein 1s;
/* Opera < 12.1 */
 animation: fadein 1s;
}
 a:link {
 position: relative;
 color: #000000;
 text-decoration: none;
}
 a:hover {
 color: #000000;
}
 a:link:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 2px;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 background-color: #000000;
 visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
 transform: scaleX(0);
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
 .nav:hover:before {
 visibility: visible;
 -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
 transform: scaleX(1);
}
 .active:hover:before {
 visibility: visible;
 -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
 transform: scaleX(1);
}
 a:link {
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 13px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
 a:link:hover {
 padding: 13px;
 -webkit-transition: height 0.5s ease;
 -moz-transition: height 0.5s ease;
 -o-transition: height 0.5s ease;
 -ms-transition: height 0.5s ease;
 transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
 -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
 -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
 -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
 -ms-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
 transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}
 a:link:active {
 padding: 13px;
 -webkit-transition: height 0.5s ease;
 -moz-transition: height 0.5s ease;
 -o-transition: height 0.5s ease;
 -ms-transition: height 0.5s ease;
 transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
 -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
 -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
 -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
 -ms-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
 transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}
 a:visited {
 color: #000000;
}
 #header.scroll {
 background-color: #000000;
 opacity: 0.5;
}
 .main {
 border-radius: 100px;
 padding: 13px;
 border: none!important;
 text-decoration: none!important 
}
 .main:hover {
 background-color: #00439F;
 color: white;
 border: none;
 padding: 13px;
 text-decoration: none!important;
 box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 position: fixed;
 margin: -13px -90px;
 border-radius: 100px;
 -webkit-animation:bounce 1s infinite;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/michalsnik/aos/2.1.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>adamferreira - Contact</title>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/michalsnik/aos/2.1.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">adamferreira</div>
<div id="navigation"
<ul>
    <a class="main" href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
    <a class="nav" href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="nav" href="contact.php">Contact</a>
    <a class="nav" href="featured.html">Featured</a>
    <a class="nav" href="story-highlights.html">Story Highlights</a>
</ul>

    
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="nav2">
    <div class="nav-header">
      <div class="nav-title"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-btn">
      <label for="nav-check">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-check">
    <div class="nav-links">
      <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
      <a href="featured.html">Featured</a>
      <a href="story-highlights.html">Story Highlights</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</head>
<body>
<div class="headerBackground"></div>

<div class="container" data-aos="ease-in-out-back" data-aos="zoom out">
<h1>Contact</h1>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..." style="font-size: 15px;">
    <input type="text2" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..." style="font-size: 15px;">
    <input type="text3" name="comment" placeholder="Type your comment..." style="font-size: 15px;">
    
    <input type="submit" class="btn" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the margin was used to align it in the centre with other elements, is there a correct way to do it more efficiently?

Comment: Check out `margin: 0 auto` or flex box for centering.

Comment: display: flex got rid of the submit button interfering with the boxes on the form but now its placed in the lower left corner of the screen.